# Problem whit trying to access to a column Java CSV

Tags: java, opencsv

I have a problem, I'm trying to access to a column from a CSV archive in JAVA. I programmed a function thats return all data from the csv archive. But I want to return 1 column depending of a condition. The condition is, the column region.

If the region number is 1, the result is, for example in SQL.

SELECT region, sum(nviv) AS 'HOUSES' FROM census WHERE region = 1

The clausure returns 1 value for region 1, a sum of all columns nviv. I trying to do same that but in JAVA and OpenCSV.

This is my code, I'm new in java programming whit CSV archives.

```
package hogares;

import java.util.*;
import com.opencsv.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Hogares {

    public static final String SEPARADOR = ";";

    public static void main(String[] args){

        int opc;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("MENU HOMES");
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("1. Count Regions by region number");
        System.out.println("2. Average of homes of blocks by region number");
        System.out.println("3. Blocks number by region number");
        System.out.println("4. Exit");
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("Select an option: ");
        opc = sc.nextInt();

        switch(opc){
            case 1:
                CountHome();
                break;
            case 2:
                AverageHome();
                break;
            case 3:
                BlocksNumber();
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("EXITING...");
                System.out.println("");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid option...");
                break;
        }
    }

    private static void CountHome(){

        int region;
        Scanner lee = new Scanner(System.in);

        BufferedReader csvr = null;
        try {


            csvr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Desktop\\census2010.csv"));

            String[] headers = new String[]{"REGION","PROVINCE","COMMUNE","DC","AREA","ZC_LOC","ID_ZONE_LOC","NVIV","NHOME","TIPE_HOME","TIPE_OPERATIVE"};

            System.out.println("Tell me a number: ");
            region = lee.nextInt();


            String line = csvr.readLine();
            while (null!=line) {
                headers = line.split(SEPARADOR);
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(headers));


                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(headers));

                line = csvr.readLine();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{

            if (csvr != null) {
                try {
                    csvr.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private static void AverageHome() {

    }

    private static void BlocksNumber() {

    }
}
```

This is the output. Remember I'm trying to return 1 result depending de number from this line:

```
System.out.println("Tell me a number: ");
region = lee.nextInt();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code comment added for explanation

```
    private static void CountHome() {

        int requestedRegion;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Tell me a number: ");
        requestedRegion = scanner.nextInt();

        try {
            FileReader filereader = new FileReader("C:\\\\Users\\\\ADMIN\\\\Desktop\\\\census2010.csv");

            // Use OpenCsv to read CSV file
            CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(filereader);

            System.out.println("REGION\tHOUSES");

            //Assign it to skip header row from records
            String[] nextLine = csvReader.readNext();

            //Take variable to for sum of nviv
            int houses = 0;

            // Read CSV record one by one
            while ((nextLine = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {

                // Get first column value which is region
                String region = nextLine[0];

                // Get nviv column value
                String nviv = nextLine[7];

                // Check region and nviv is not null and empty
                if (region != null && !region.isEmpty() && nviv != null && !region.isEmpty()) {

                    // Parse region string to integer
                    int currentRegion = Integer.parseInt(region);

                    // Check row region is equals to region entered by user
                    if (currentRegion == requestedRegion) {

                        // Parse nviv sting to integer
                        int currentNviv = Integer.parseInt(nviv);

                        // Sum nviv And get total houses
                        houses = houses + currentNviv;

                        // System.out.println(region + "\t" + nviv);
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Invalid data to proceed");
                }
            }
            System.out.println(requestedRegion + "\t" + houses);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Sample CSV Data:

```
REGION,PROVINCE,COMMUNE,DC,AREA,ZC_LOC,ID_ZONE_LOC,NVIV,NHOME,TIPE_HOME,TIPE_OPERATIVE
1,2,33,4,5,66,7,8,9,10,11
2,2,33,4,5,66,7,8,9,10,11
1,2,33,4,5,66,7,8,9,10,11
2,2,33,4,5,66,7,8,9,10,11
1,2,33,4,5,66,7,8,9,10,11
1,2,33,4,5,66,7,8,9,10,11
7,2,33,4,5,66,7,8,9,10,11
7,2,33,4,5,66,7,8,9,10,11
7,2,33,4,5,66,7,8,9,10,11
7,2,33,4,5,66,7,8,9,10,11
7,2,33,4,5,66,7,8,9,10,11
8,2,33,4,5,66,7,8,9,10,11
8,2,33,4,5,66,7,8,9,10,11
8,2,33,4,5,66,7,8,9,10,11
8,2,33,4,5,66,7,8,9,10,11
8,2,33,4,5,66,7,8,9,10,11
```

Output:

```
MENU HOMES

1. Count Regions by region number
2. Average of homes of blocks by region number
3. Blocks number by region number
4. Exit

Select an option: 
1
Tell me a number: 
7
REGION  HOUSES
7   40
```

Can Result with error if CSV have empty row,

To check if any empty row exsist and skip if found

```
           // Read CSV record one by one
            while ((nextLine = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {

                // Check row empty, if found skip iteration
                if (nextLine.length != 0 && nextLine[0].trim().isEmpty()) {
                    continue;
                }
```

Comment: You can´t simply put only code without an explanation, that explain what's do the code. Now I have an error, that's says: ```java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
 at homes.Homes.CountHome(Homes.java:69)
 at homes.Homes.main(Homes.java:31)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)``` And I don't know how to resolve that error.

Comment: Edited for explanation, error you are getting right now can never produce with code we have right now at both question and answer because error says it is throwing from Homes.java class. And I haven't seen it. ArrayaindexOutOfBounds occurs when you are assessing array with index 7 but array size is less than 7. Occurs at line no 69 in Homes.java

Comment: My main class is named Homes  and maybe I didn't say, The csv archive has many rows. And the column region (at the same time) has many rows, not only 1 data, for example: Region is divided in 15 regions, and each region has over than 1000 rows.

Comment: The error you got can occur, answer edited to solve it.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'm got another error, I declared a variable called SEPARATOR. And I didn't using, now I resolve the error and is fully functional.